# Positioning two brands' logos on application header

Tags: desktop-application, header, branding, logos

I am designing an application that has two brands' logos to be displayed on the header. Positioning two brand logos next to each other looks odd.

Which is the best way to position the logos on the header?

[image]

Comment: Welcome Kevin! Could you share a little more context? What's the reason for needing two logos? What's the relationship between the two?

Comment: The context of this usability is to display both my brand logo as well as my customer's brand logo on the header.

Comment: Is there a hierarchical relationship between the two? Should one be more prominent than the other?

Comment: There is no hierarchical relationship between those brands, they are my customer. I think customer brand logo can be prominent than another one.

Comment: What is the rationale / business reason for having your logo on there at all? If your customer is paying you for the site then it's their site, not yours. Can you elaborate on that part so people don't focus on the wrong part of this question?

Comment: I've done somethin like this. For a vineyard with included tavern. One logo on the left, one logo on the right. Main menu in the middle. One of the most stupid things I ever had to do. You need to solve so many problems like different viewport sizes, mobile menus, e.g. And it looks so horrible. Never again!

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to have the customer's logo up top (since they're the paying customer) and your logo in the footer, in a "powered by" sort of display? Similar to a customized WordPress site. The client customizes the site with their brand, but the very bottom prominently states that the site was created with WordPress. Just a thought. It's hard to know without more context of the site, the industry, the logos, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is very difficult to answer because I don't know what your logos look like.

However, I would consider putting the Brand Logo 2 on the left side before the user and notification icons. This is because on many websites these things will be the very last things in the header and having them just before the logo. (Like in your second picture) could be confusing.

This might end up looking horrible though (depending on the icon) so you should definitely have a bunch of end users look at multiple possibilities to chose.

Answer (score 0):

We did it for Leica / Hexagon see and I think it looks good.

The original version did not include the Hexagon logo, which was introduced several years after Hexagon acquired Leica Geosystems, and even later in the US.  See

[image: old version]

Initially, we were uncertain about combining the two logos, but upon seeing the result, we felt that they blended quite naturally, with the Hexagon logo appearing first as the parent company, and the Leica logo appearing second as the subsidiary. See below

[image: new version]

Of course, this may vary depending on the specific logos involved.

Additionally, I recall that at one point, NBA.com used two logos when redirecting to Argentina's version due to its association with a sports newspaper there.

Comment: wow just realized this is an old old post, we should really delete these ones

Comment: Appreciate your help, Devin! This might help others.

Comment: Comes first up in Google - they do help